# How to create MS Access Report With dynamic number of columns

Tags: ms-access

I am building a report in MS Access based on a crosstab query. Therefore I do not know the number of columns or column headers in advance. I have created a template report with one column. In VBA I make a copy of this template report. Using the report recordsource, I then add labels to the report header and textboxes to the report detail and give the report headers the correct name. I set the label and textbox properties using the settings of the label and textbox from the template report. All this is done in VBA.
Is there a better way to create a report with dynamic number of columns? If not, using VBA, is it possible to add columns to the report grid and snap the labels and textboxes that were dynamically created to the grid.

Comment: Easier? No. Snap controls to grid with VBA? Maybe. Do research and when you have code with specific issue, post question. As is, your question is too broad, lacks code for analysis, and indicates no effort to solve issue. All of which makes this question not suitable for SO.

Comment: An alternative approach I have used to generate some very simplistic output is VBA procedure to concatenate all data to a single string and display in a single textbox set for a non-proportional font. Code formats fixed width for each 'column' and embedded CrLf to force line breaks. Requires data from each field to be limited in width. The column headers would be included. Can do some formatting with HTML tags and textbox set for RichText. If output is numeric, it works really nice.

Comment: I looked for code that would select a control and snap it to grid and came up with zilch. What you can do is specify Left and Top properties of control. You could pull the Top and Left values from the established textbox. All controls would use the same Top value then calculate Left position of each created control.

Comment: But I suspect you are already doing that in your current code. So, why the interest in snapping to grid?